# NSArray Leak inside setCompletionBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, objective-c-blocks, nsoperationqueue

### Edit to Question: 21/10/2013 20:10 GMT

Added how the method is called below and also the object that is leaking is "allDBObjects" If i remove this and change the dictionary below to "NSMutableDictionary *objectsById" there is no leak.

### Edit to Question: 21/10/2013

After a few days not on this issue I have come back to it. I believe this is all down to "The Deallocation Problem" (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2109/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010274-CH1-SUBSECTION11). I have tested with both MKNetworkKit and AFNetworking 1.3.3 (Changing 1 method to use AFNetworking instead of MKNetwork Kit) and am still getting these objects leaking in my completion block. I have no references to self within my block and using AFNetworking I can see the completionBlock is set to nil and I have tried to manually break the retain cycle by setting the [weakOp setCompletionBlock:nil].

**EDIT**: The code sample below I tried to use properties and reference them as weakSelf. I have now changed these to local variables and they still leak.

Any ideas?

### Original Question

I have taken over a project using MKNetworkKit and Core Data, after running the project through Leaks in instruments I can see a lot of leaked objects in various places in the app.

After debugging the code I can see the objects that are leaking are 2 fetch requests that are happening in the callback of a MKNetworkKit request (setCompletionBlock:). The fetch requests need to be done to check whether the data needs to be inserted or updated.

Some further information. Inside the completion block I am getting an instance of the ManagedObjectContext and creating it with concurrency type of "NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType" and to perform the insert I am correctly calling "performBlock:" on the moc.

Please advise.

James

Sample Code of Block:
Please note: I have commented out the 2 fetch requests are there are no leaks and putting them back in causes the leaks of hundreds of objects, also the weakSelf properties I am setting the NSDictionary and NSArray are (nonatomic, strong).

```
- (void) updateDbObjects: (int) page withCallback: (CompletionResultsNumberBlock) callback {  

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self createFullPath:urlStr]]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [weakSelf managedObjectContextForCurrentThread];
    DataRoot *dataRoot = [DataRoot sharedInstanceInMoc:moc];
    
    NSArray *returnJSON = JSON[@"object"];
    __block int count = returnJSON.count;
            
    if (!count)
    {
        dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
            callback(0);
        });
        return;
    }
    
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"DBObjects"];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *allDBObjects = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    
    NSMutableDictionary *objectsById = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:allTeamsArray forKeys:[allTeamsArray valueForKey: GoalTeamObjectAttributes.teamId]];
            
    for (NSDictionary *rootDict in returnJSON)
    {
        GoalTeamObject *dbObject =  objectsById[rootDict[@"id"]];
        
        if (dbObject == nil)
        {
            dbObject = [DBObjects insertInManagedObjectContext:dataRoot.managedObjectContext];
        } 

        [weakSelf importStandardParametersFrom:rootDict into:dbObject withPrefix:@""];
        
    }
    
    returnJSON = nil;
    objectsById = nil;
    
    [dataRoot saveContext];
    
    NSError *childError = nil;
    
    if ([moc save:&childError]) {
        
        NSError *parentError = nil;
        if (![moc.parentContext save:&parentError]) {
            NSLog(@"Error saving parent");
        }
        
        dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
            callback(count);
        });
        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error saving child");
    }
    
    
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
    
}];
    
[operation start];

 }
```

This is how this code is called: It is called recursively in a loop as there are many pages of data.

```
__block int page = 1;

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

CompletionResultsNumberBlock loadData;

__block CompletionResultsNumberBlock block_loadData = loadData = ^(int results)
{
    if (results < 100)
    {
        dispatch_async(callerQueue, callback);
    } else {
        [weakSelf updateDbObjects:++page withCallback:block_loadData];
    }
};

[self updateDbObjects:page withCallback: loadData];
```

Comment: Can you show the source of the completion block?

Comment: you can post some code?

Comment: @jodm: how is `weakOp` defined?

Comment: Added how weakOp is defined to code above. Also added missing DataRoot class.

Comment: 1) It can be profiler bug. However, it's almost impossible 2) Are you sure, that leaking objects are NSFetchRequests? Commenting them out and getting leaks away doesn't mean they are leaking. 3) Everything seems OK to me in your code, it's either magic or not enough info.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look right:

```
__block CompletionResultsNumberBlock block_loadData = loadData = ^...
```

Under ARC, the block would hold a strong reference to itself. Under ARC, you should do:

```
__block __weak CompletionResultsNumberBlock block_loadData = loadData = ^...
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `weakSelf` in some places within the block, and `self` in others.  That means that the block will still capture `self` in a strong fashion.

I'd try replacing **all** references to `self` with `weakSelf` within your block first.

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to edit the code when I added my edit. All references to self in the block are now weakSelf. I will update the code further but I have also removed the properties and using local vars.

Comment: Ok...I still see at least two references to self within your block.  Maybe showing the simplest block of code that reproduces the problem would be helpful?

Comment: It is the "allDBObjects" that is leaking. If I comment this out and put "NSMutableDictionary *objectsById;" instead of the dictionary there is no leak.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, after looking at your edits my face resembled the logo from Jeff Atwood's Coding Horror.  I hope someone else can untangle this for you, but to me it would take way more than the 50 reputation points in the bounty to do so.

Comment: I would like to add this isn't my code and it is a project I have taken over ;)

Comment: @jodm I understand that you weren't the original author, but since you've taken over the project I would argue that this **is** your code.  I've been in your situation before and I wouldn't want to maintain this code either.  Don't be afraid to use that Delete key and add more value by building something that is way more maintainable and comprehensible!